# string replacement in page created from template

Tags: c#, asp.net, templates, string, escaping

I've got some aspx pages being created by the user from a template.  Included is some string replacement (anyting with ${fieldname}), so a portion of the template looks like this:

```
<% 
  string title = @"${title}";
%>
<title><%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(title) %></title>
```

When an aspx file is created from this template, the ${title} gets replaced by the value the user entered.

But obviously they can inject arbitrary HTML by just closing the double quote in their input string.  How do I get around this?  I feel like it should be obvious, but I can't figure a way around this.

I have no control over the template instantiating process -- I need to accept that as a given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you store their values in another file(xml maybe) or in a database?  That way their input is not compiled into your page.  Then you just read the data into variables.  Then all you have to worry about is html, which your html encode would take care of.

Comment: This seems like the only way it could work -- the value gets put in some kind of holding area and then a separate process reads and injects it into the aspx template.

Answer (score 0):

If they include a double quote in their string, that will not inject arbitrary HTML, but arbitrary code, which is even worse.

You can use a regex to filter the input string.  I would use an inclusive regex rathern than trying to exclude dangerous chars.  Only allow them A-Za-z0-9 and whitespace.

Comment: You're right, they can insert either code or html, either one.

As in my comment to the other answer, I can't get it into a variable to begin with, so it's hard to process it after the fact.


This operation will be done by logged-in users, not the public, so it may just be something I can live with.  But I was hoping there was a way around this just to avoid crabbing from the IT staff.

Comment: do you not control  the code that applies the variables to the template?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure i understand fully, but...

Try using a regex to strip html from the title instead of html encoding it:

```
public string StripHTML(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
}
```

Is this possible?

```
<% 
  string title = Regex.Replace(@"${title}", @”<(.|\n)*?>”, string.Empty);
%>
```

or

```
<title><%=HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(title, @"<(.|\n)*?>", string.Empty)) %></title>
```

Comment: And how do I safely get the template-replaced text into the variable 'text'?  That's the whole problem!

Comment: How are the end users creating the templates?  why can you filter the content on save instead of on display?

Comment: I'm creating the template -- the code in my question is code I have control over.

They're pushing a button saying, "Create a new file from template" and they get a form where they can fill in the 'title'.  The file that's created gets a copy of the template file with all the ${} tags replaced.

Comment: I would still do processing on the form submit, if possible so is inst done every time the page is rendered.